# how to upload data to server? pass with <parameter> and this will return <id>?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I want to upload data into server. it pass with  and this will return , how i can do?
Please help me

Code is just example

```
but4.addEventListener('click',function(){

var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({
timeout : '15000',
});

xhr.onload = function (){
Titanium.API.info('onload');
Ti.API.info('Sucess'+ this.status + '  '+ this.readyState);
};

xhr.onerror = function(){
Ti.API.info('error');
res.hide();
};

xhr.ondatastream=function(){
Ti.API.info('ondatastream');
};
var abc1 = 'iPhone_request=<category><name>game_abc</name></category>';

xhr.open('POST','http://www.imobdevtech.com/assignments/uploadcategory.php');
xhr.send(abc1);
});
```

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This, I think this very help to you,

```
xhr.send({iPhone_request='<category><name>Game Name</name></category>'});
```